# My HTML website does not scroll in the mobile

Tags: android, ios, mobile, responsive

This [website](http://www.virtux.io) does not scroll on mobile device. I have been searching for some solutions but none of them work.

The website scrolls and bit, then stops, then you can, is not working properly.

Comment: what is `mobile view`? is it a `webview`? or you're just opening your site in mobile browser?

Comment: just opening the site in a mobile browser

Comment: which one browser?

Comment: I have tried chrome and firefox and none of them works

Comment: I have tried Chrome and everything works fine

Comment: mmm interesting, it does not freeze or stops after scrolling a little bit, and trying it again?

Comment: you may try it buy yourself. for example, open Google Chrome on desktop -> right click -> inspect -> in right top corner icon with devices (toggle device toolbar) -> and choose some mobile phone

Comment: If you try it like this it works, but when you open it with a real mobile it does not work

Answer (score 0):

The scroll happens only on the right top and right bottom check whether it is due to the hotjar.js or try adding this to the 
`-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` in css for html element